# How to avoid duplicate with MySQl in Auto-suggest

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autosuggest

How can I avoid duplicate return data with MYSQL with autosuggest with this code?
Thank you so much for helping

```
   <?php
include('conn.php');
$str = strtolower($_GET['content']);         
if(strlen($str))
{
    $sel = mysql_query("select * from Streams where title like '".trim($str)."%'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sel))
    {
        echo "<table border =\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n";
        if(mysql_num_rows($sel))
        {
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">box('1');</script>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
            {
                $country = str_ireplace($str,"<b>".$str."</b>",($row['title']));
                echo "<tr id=\"word".$row['title']."\" onmouseover=\"highlight(1,'".$row['title']."');\" onmouseout=\"highlight(0,'".$row['title']."');\" onClick=\"display('".$row['title']."');\" >\n<td>".$country."</td>\n</tr>\n";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}                                 
else
{
    echo "<script language=\"javascript\">box('0');</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see in your code is that there is only a single field - `title` - from the SQL resultset that you are using in the PHP code. So why not instead write your query as:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT `title`
FROM Streams 
WHERE title like '".trim($str)."%'"
```

Or perhaps if you can't change the query, you may store the `title` in a PHP array and then run `array_unique` on it to avoid duplicates before writing them to HTML.

Comment: I agree with the comment by "mu is too short" to use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape your data before passing to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, it seems like you're only using the "title" field from your database. You could do this:

```
$sel = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM Streams WHERE title LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($str))."%'");
```

As per the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> The [...] DISTINCT options specify
>   whether duplicate rows should be
>   returned. [...] DISTINCT specifies
>   removal of duplicate rows from the
>   result set. It is an error to specify
>   both options.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need to select distinct elements

```
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(title) FROM Streams WHERE title LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($str))."%'");
```

Ofcourse if any reason you cant do that, 
Put the data in a array and check if it was previously added to prevent duplication, define array outside the while

```
    $data = array()
    if (!in_array($row["title"], $data)){
     \\do your thing
       array_push($data, $row["title");
     }
```